# how to overlay a pandas plot, matplotlib plot, and axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have one plot in the format:

```
df.plot()
```

The other one is in the format:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(t,y,'b-')
```

I cannot convert the first plot into the standard matplotlib plot because it is resampled from a pandas timeseries.

How do I overlay the two plots?

Answer (score 4):

Try `df.plot(ax=ax)`. This causes the dataframe object to be plotted in the supplied axis.