# Show a Pandas plot from a script

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a script (not an IPython notebook) that produces a plot at the end (via a pandas `DataFrame`). My problem is that such a plot is not showing.

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389300/how-to-overlay-a-pandas-plot-matplotlib-plot-and-axis) I have tried

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
my_dataframe.plot(ax=ax)
ax.show()
```

which does not work. The only way I can show my plot is:

```
plt.figure()
my_dataframe.plot()
plt.show()
```

but this brings up also a empty figure that I don't want to have.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you try

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
my_dataframe.plot(ax=ax)
plt.show() # plt in place of ax
```

Comment: For people not used to these abbreviations: plt referers to 

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`